# Disconnecting mysql connections in ruby after a timeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, puma

My network firewall kills any idle connections after a few minutes. This is causing our rails app to keep reconnecting and eventually the database starts refusing connections because the max connection limit is hit. Unfortunatley I don't have the ability to change the network or the database.

I am looking for a way to preemptively disconnect after 1 minute idle time on each connection. I wanted to log a timestamp on each connection in the pool by prepending on:

ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::MysqlAdapter#execute
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/MysqlAdapter/execute

basically

```
attr_reader :last_used_at
def execute 
  @last_used_at = Time.now 
  super
end
```

Then have a connection_disconnector thread run on rails startup that goes through each connection and disconnects (#disconnect!) any that that have been idle for more than a minute.

This works fine in webrick, however in puma for some reason the @last_used_at instance variable that gets set in the MysqlAdapater on execute can not be read by the connection_disconnector. I can see all the connections in the connection pool, however when I check their timestamps they are all blank.

I guess it has something to do with the way puma and mysql work together to keep each threads state separate? I'm at a loss here. Any pointers would be super helpful.